# Kick command won't kick people when used

Tags: python, discord.py, command, bots

I tried to make a kick command, everything works except when the command is run, the user specified will not be kicked.

```
@bot.tree.command(name='kick', description='Kicks a user from the server [S]')
async def embed(interaction : discord.Interaction, user : discord.Member, reason : str = None):

    permissions = interaction.user.guild_permissions
    is_admin = permissions.kick_members
    kick = user.guild.kick

    if is_admin == True:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Kick Command', color=discord.Color.blurple(), description='Kicks a user.')
        embed.set_author( name = f'{interaction.user}', icon_url= f'{interaction.user.display_avatar}')
        await kick
        embed.add_field(name = 'Username', value=str(user.mention), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name = 'Reason', value=str(reason), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name = 'Moderation', value='User kicked successfully.', inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="Command called by: {}".format(interaction.user))
        embed.set_image(url='image')
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed)
```

I tried the code above and it didn't work, all the code works as expected except that.

Comment: Are you sure `permissions.kick_members` is true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, and work your way from there:

The command should be !kick @user reason for kick

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
bot= commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
#adjust intents appropriately for your bot 

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await bot.kick(member)
    await ctx.channel.send(f'User {member} has been kicked')
```

Comment: this doesn't work, with the code above, what would the code be to kick someone?

Comment: HaxDX, thank you for letting me know, hopefully the edit works